# Does Caesar know of Jesus?

Tags: jesus

> 17 Tell us therefore, what thinkest thou? Is it lawful to give tribute unto Caesar, or not?” 18 But Jesus perceived their wickedness and said, “Why tempt ye Me, ye hypocrites? 19 Show Me the tribute money.” And they brought unto Him a penny. 20 And He said unto them, “Whose is this image and superscription?” 21 And they said unto Him, “Caesar’s.” Then said He unto them, “Render therefore unto Caesar the things which are Caesar’s, and unto God the things that are God’s.” - **Matthew 22:17-21 KJ21**

Clearly, Jesus knows of Caesar. Does Caesar know of Jesus? If not, after all the heavenly things Jesus did in Judea, how come they've never spread to Rome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pilate was keen to keep matters quiet. Only when threatened by the crowd did Pilate relinquish and give the order for Jesus' crucifixion :

> And from thenceforth Pilate sought to release him: but the Jews cried out, saying, If thou let this man go, thou art not Caesar's friend: whosoever maketh himself a king speaketh against Caesar. John 19:12 KJV

The threat appears to me to be that they will involve Caesar. So, presumably, he knows nothing as yet.

The evidence would suggest that Caesar did not already know of any trouble or disturbance caused in Judaea through either John the Baptist's or Jesus' ministry.

It is an interesting point, however, that Herod Antipas, son of Herod the Great, executed John the Baptist but in Jesus' case, Herod sent Jesus to Pilate for examination and execution.

Again, I would suggest that that indicates an unwillingnes on Herod's part to bring matters to Caesar's attention. He can quietly dispose of John, maybe. But not so, some three years later, when multitudes have followed John on to following Jesus and the movement has persisted and grown.

Comment: True, the governor and Antipas might want to keep it quiet but I was thinking perhaps via trade, travellers, migration etc. those stories could get to Rome and eventually the emperor.

Comment: @Will Well we can only go by evidence. The rest is conjecture.